# try to make a multi language datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a datepicker, and using uib-datepicker-popup format to change datepicker's language.
html file:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-date ng-valid-required" show-button-bar="false" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly="" required="required" ng-init="initDt()" ng-change="changeDt()">
```

js:

```
if ($scope.langCode == "jpn") {
    $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy年m月d日';
     } else if($scope.langCode == "eng") {
    $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy/m/d';
     }
```

[image]

the problem is the month auto increases (over 12) everytime i change date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `m` is used to parse the minutes, not the month like you are expecting. Use `M` or `MM` instead to parse the month.

Check the `Dateparser` docs here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to see what all the formatting codes refer to.